# iptables nat not work for sctp

Tags: linux, iptables

i have a server in internal network and i want to access it from external.

the network is like this:
Server A (132.196.28.229) is in external network 
Server B (10.35.202.24) can access both network
Server C (192.168.10.99) is in internal network

So, i configure iptables on Server B to forward all traffic from Server A to Server C

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.35.202.24 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.99
```

Then i test it with ping and it works. 
Tcpdump on Server B, you can see the ping from Server A and target is **10.35.202.24**:

```
15:34:36.366034 IP 132.196.28.229 > 10.35.202.24: ICMP echo request, id 24510, seq 1, length 64
15:34:37.366321 IP 132.196.28.229 > 10.35.202.24: ICMP echo request, id 24510, seq 2, length 64
15:34:38.374983 IP 132.196.28.229 > 10.35.202.24: ICMP echo request, id 24510, seq 3, length 64
15:34:39.374849 IP 132.196.28.229 > 10.35.202.24: ICMP echo request, id 24510, seq 4, length
```

and Tcpdump on Server C. now the target adress is changed to **192.168.10.99**:

```
15:34:35.741802 IP 132.196.28.229 > 192.168.10.99: ICMP echo request, id 24510, seq 1, length 64
15:34:36.742018 IP 132.196.28.229 > 192.168.10.99: ICMP echo request, id 24510, seq 2, length 64
15:34:37.750633 IP 132.196.28.229 > 192.168.10.99: ICMP echo request, id 24510, seq 3, length 64
15:34:38.750499 IP 132.196.28.229 > 192.168.10.99: ICMP echo request, id 24510, seq 4, length 64
```

but, same forwarding not work for SCTP message. 
Here is the INIT message i triggered from Server A:

```
15:39:18.787145 IP 132.196.28.229.32763 > 10.35.202.24.36412: sctp (1) [INIT] [init tag: 495530240] [rwnd: 62464] [OS: 64] [MIS: 64] [init TSN: 322647100] 
15:39:18.787189 IP 10.35.202.24 > 132.196.28.229: ICMP 10.35.202.24 protocol 132 unreachable, length 76
15:39:21.786640 IP 132.196.28.229.32763 > 10.35.202.24.36412: sctp (1) [INIT] [init tag: 495530240] [rwnd: 62464] [OS: 64] [MIS: 64] [init TSN: 322647100] 
15:39:21.786687 IP 10.35.202.24 > 132.196.28.229: ICMP 10.35.202.24 protocol 132 unreachable, length 76
```

And i can't capture anything on Server C for sctp.  Looks like that the NAT for sctp not work, and due to server B don't have any sctp service on.  so the server B reply as unreachable.

I have tested ssh as well. The forwarding works well.  so it looks only not working for SCTP!!??

Any suggestion why this happen? is any special configure for sctp i missed?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing some modules in the Linux kernel. Try this:

```
modprobe nf_conntrack_proto_sctp
modprobe nf_nat_proto_sctp
```